# Is there any conditions on a finite abelian group so that it cannot be class group of any number field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The Cohen-Lenstra paper says the probability that the odd part of a class group being cyclic is close to 0.98. So I was thinking: can we find any conditions on a finite abelian group so that it cannot be a class group of any number field?

Comment: related discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/finite-abelian-groups-as-class-groups

Comment: @YCor I'd think "old part" probably should be "odd part"...

Comment: Actually, the passage from Cohen--Lenstra that the question refers to concerns class groups of imaginary quadratic fields. The paper makes no statements about the statistics of class groups of all number fields.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It follows from the Cohen-Lenstra heuristic that every finite abelian group is expected to be isomorphic to infinitely many class groups of real quadratic fields (even to a positive proportion of real quadratics, which is stronger), but nothing like this is known.

However, if you take the Galois action into account, then things get interesting: there are Galois modules that are not isomorphic to any class group of a Galois number field with the respective Galois group. See Corollary 4.12 and the discussion following it on page 20 in this paper of mine with Lenstra: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06903v4. We show there that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $58$, then there are finite $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules that cannot be realised as the class group of a $G$-extension.

Of course, there are cheap ways of doing that, by considering modules whose fixed submodule is something silly, contradicting the fact that the class group of $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial, but that is not what is happening in our paper. For example our obstruction cannot be seen by looking at any particular $p$-Sylow of the class group.